# Is there a way to store a previously clicked element in vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I know I'm close to the solution but perhaps I'm looking at it wrong. What I want my relationship SVG chart to do is store the previously clicked element and then compare it to the next element clicked.

If the elements are the same, toggle "is-selected" to hide the relationship lines. If they are different, show the lines of the clicked element and hide the previous element's lines. If there is no previous element, show the lines of the clicked element.

Unfortunately, right now it's telling me that elementClicked is undefined.

```
        var characterList = document.querySelectorAll('[id$="-image"]');
        var elementClicked;
        var lastElementClicked;
        [...characterList].forEach(function (characterImage) {
            characterImage.addEventListener("click", function(){

                elementClicked = characterImage;

                function toggleRelationship(element) {
                    element.firstElementChild.classList.toggle("is-selected");
                    element.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("st0");
                }

                if (elementClicked == lastElementClicked) {

                    console.log("element is equal to last element");
                    toggleRelationship(elementClicked);

                } else if ( elementClicked != lastElementClicked && lastElementClicked.classList.contains("is-selected") ) {

                    console.log("element is not equal to last element");
                    toggleRelationship(lastElementClicked);

                } else {

                    console.log("element was clicked and is stored");
                    toggleRelationship(elementClicked);
                    lastElementClicked = elementClicked;

                }

            });
        });
```

Edit: Thanks for the heads up on the comparison Brian! I changed it. Issue still remains though.

Comment: You need to use == for comparison (elementClicked = lastElementClicked will assign undefined to elementClicked, if lastElementClicked is not initalized).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I want you to take a look at your conditions carefully. At first condition you check `if (elementClicked == lastElementClicked) { /* code here */ }`. And at the second `else if (elementClicked != lastElementClicked && /* other conditions here */)`. But second condition will not run in case when `elementClicked == lastElementClicked`, so, this part of condition useless: `elementClicke != lastElentClicked`.

Second, after removing that condition from `else if` block, we will got `else if (lastElementClicked.classList.contains('is-selected'))`, but after first run your lastElementClicked will be equal to undefined. You should skip this block in case your element undefined, for example in this way: `else if (lastElementClicked && lastElementClicked.classList.contains('is-selected'))`. It will be even better if you will check not only element existing, but even the type and path to needed property (take a look at `typeof`, `instanseof`, `Object.porotype.hasOwnProperty`, etc).

I hope I explain everything clearly enough, because I remember the time I had the same problems understanding js.